Appsync real-time api integration with an existing app
I already have two graphql api in Appsync which have cognito user pools as primary authorization. Now, I want to implement a chat feature. So, basically there are two apps respectively. Coach and user. I created a real-time api(third api in appsync) and it's working fine. Is there any way to implement it in the existing applications? As, amplify doesn't allow codegen for more than 1 api.
I tried invoking appsync using axios. It needs alot of work around. So, in order to make the flow lighter, I'm just in search of a way to integrate the existing real-time api with the existing apps(such a way that chat works common)
